# Service crash, even with startForeground when the activity gets shut down and the alarmManager sets off

Tags: android, service, alarmmanager

I have mainActivity that starts service with START_STICKY onStartCommand, in that service I also use startForeground and alarmManager repeater. When I close the main activity by swiping the app away, service is still running, and the notification icon from the startForeground remains, however, when the alarm from the alarmManager sets off inside service, the service get crashed and restart itself within 5000 ms. Why does the service crash soon as it gets to setting of an alarm?

MainActivity.java:

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Messenger;
import android.util.Log;
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    Messenger mService = null;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        CheckIfServiceIsRunning();
    }
    private void CheckIfServiceIsRunning() {
        if (MyService.isRunning()) {
        } else {
            startService(new Intent(MainActivity.this, MyService.class));
        }
    }
    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        //stopService(new Intent(MainActivity.this, MyService.class)); //disabled line so that killing UI-app doesn't kill service aswell
    }
}
```

MyService.java:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.Timer;
import java.util.TimerTask;
import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.app.AlarmManager;
import android.app.Notification;
import android.app.PendingIntent;
import android.app.Service;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.os.IBinder;
import android.os.Message;
import android.os.Messenger;
import android.util.Log;
public class MyService extends Service {
    public AlarmManager alarmManager;
    public PendingIntent pendingIntent;
    private Timer timer = new Timer();
    private int counter = 0, incrementby = 1;
    private static boolean isRunning = false;
    final public static int NOTIFICATION_FOREGROUND = 34444;
    ArrayList<Messenger> mClients = new ArrayList<Messenger>();
    final Messenger mMessenger = new Messenger(new IncomingHandler());
    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return mMessenger.getBinder();
    }
    @SuppressLint("HandlerLeak")
    class IncomingHandler extends Handler {
        @Override
        public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
            super.handleMessage(msg);
        }
    }
    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        Log.i("MyService", "---- Service Started. ----");
        timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(new TimerTask(){ public void run() {onTimerTick();}}, 0, 1000L);
        isRunning = true;
        StartForegroundNotification();
        alarmManager = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
        Intent broadcast_intent = new Intent(this, MyAlarmReceiver.class); 
        pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0,  broadcast_intent, 0);
        Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
        calendar.setTimeInMillis(System.currentTimeMillis());
        alarmManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar.getTimeInMillis(), 10*1000, pendingIntent);
    }
    @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
    public void StartForegroundNotification(){
        String title = "Service Title";
        String message = "Service Message";
        Notification notify = new Notification(R.drawable.ic_launcher, null, 0);            
        Intent notifIntent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);          
        PendingIntent i = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, notifIntent, 0);
        notify.setLatestEventInfo(this, title, message, i);
        notify.flags |= Notification.FLAG_NO_CLEAR;
        startForeground(NOTIFICATION_FOREGROUND, notify);
    }
    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        Log.i("MyService", "Received start id " + startId + ": " + intent);
        return START_STICKY;
    }
    public static boolean isRunning()
    {
        return isRunning;
    }
    private void onTimerTick() {
        Log.i("TimerTick", "Timer doing work." + counter);
        try {
            counter += incrementby;
        } catch (Throwable t) {
            Log.e("TimerTick", "Timer Tick Failed.", t);            
        }
    }
    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        alarmManager.cancel(pendingIntent);
        if (timer != null) {timer.cancel();}
        stopForeground(true);
        counter=0;
        Log.i("MyService", "---- Service Stopped. ----");
        isRunning = false;
    }
}
```

MyAlarmReceiver.java:

```
import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.util.Log;
public class MyAlarmReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver { 
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        Log.i("alarmer", "I got it");
    }
}
```

and in manifest I used:

```
<service android:name=".MyService" />
<receiver android:name=".MyAlarmReceiver" />
```

and the logcat (soon as it hit alarm time - after timer ticks 3 in this case - it crashed if the app is closed, however, after it restarts itself, it will not be crashed again, I guess because it's being started from different context, and not from MainActivity.this, it gets "null" intent in onStartCommand):

```
12-16 19:08:50.614: I/TimerTick(27069): Timer doing work.1
12-16 19:08:53.614: I/TimerTick(27069): Timer doing work.2
12-16 19:08:56.614: I/TimerTick(27069): Timer doing work.3
12-16 19:08:57.622: I/ActivityManager(395): Killing 27069:com.example.serviceexample/u0a10097: remove task
12-16 19:08:57.629: W/ActivityManager(395): Scheduling restart of crashed service com.example.serviceexample/.MyService in 5000ms
12-16 19:09:02.661: I/ActivityManager(395): Start proc com.example.serviceexample for service com.example.serviceexample/.MyService: pid=27100 uid=10097 gids={50097, 1028}
12-16 19:09:02.715: I/MyService(27100): ---- Service Started. ----
12-16 19:09:02.715: I/TimerTick(27100): Timer doing work.0
12-16 19:09:02.723: I/MyService(27100): Received start id 3: null
```

Comment: A legitimate crash with a log cat output or Android decides to kill the service?

Comment: edited the post, added log cat data. Not a legitimate crash, but more of a restart. The service is being killed by the ActivityManager, and then being restarted by the very same ActivityManager as a "crashed service"